# How does higher order function and Set work on Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

1. Write a higher-order function twice that takes as a parameter a function of one argument and returns a function that represents the application of that function to its argument twice. Given the usual definition of the square function, what function is (twice (twice square))?

```
usage: (twice square)
=> #<procedure>
```

```
usage: ((twice square) 2)
=> 16
```

```
usage: ((twice (twice square)) 10)
=> 10000000000000000
```

2. Suppose that you want to use a list data structure to implement a Set data type. Write insert and member operations. (You may have to rename the functions to avoid naming conflicts.)

```
usage: (member 4 (list 1 2 4))  
=> #t
```

```
usage: (insert 4 (list 1 2))
=> (4 1 2)
```

I've tried the below code for problem 2, (and it did not work the way I wanted), andhHow  have no idea for problem 1

```
(define (set? lst)      
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((member? (car lst) (cdr lst)) #f)
        (else (set? (cdr lst)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Higher order functions are functions that take functions as arguments (or return function as result). You define them the same way as normal functions, with `define`. For example, [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) has procedure (in Racket, functions are called procedures) as the first argument and it calls that procedure on each element of list:

```
> (map add1 '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(2 3 4 5 6)
> (map sub1 '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(0 1 2 3 4)
```

Imagine that you want increase each number by two with `map`. You could define named function for that:

```
(define (add2 x) (+ x 2))

> (map add2 '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(3 4 5 6 7)
```

or use [`lambda`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._lambda%29%29), which creates anonymous function:

```
> (map (lambda (x) (+ x 2))
       '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(3 4 5 6 7)
```

This function can't be called from other places in your program (unless you bound it to some symbol) and is discarded after use.

Function created by `lambda` can be also returned as result. Maybe you often need add some number and you don't want to write `(lambda (x) ... )` everytime. So, you can write function like this:

```
(define (adder y)
  (lambda (x) (+ x y)))
```

and use it with `map`:

```
> (map (adder 3) '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(4 5 6 7 8)
> (map (adder 4) '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(5 6 7 8 9)
```

Note that created anonymous function remembers, that `y = 3` or `y = 4`. Actually, all functions in Racket are *lexical closures*, they remember, where they were created and which symbols were bound in that moment.

So, your solution will use these principles:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (twice f)
  (lambda (x) (f (f x))))
```

Then, `((twice (twice square)) 10)` can be rewritten as

```
> ((lambda (x) ((lambda (x) (square (square x)))
               ((lambda (x) (square (square x)))
               x))) 10)
10000000000000000
```

and that is 10^16.

```
> (= ((twice (twice square)) 10)
     (expt 10 16))
#t
```

2. I'm not sure if you need to write some other fuctions than `member` and `insert`, because in your example, they are called on list and no `list->set` function is explicitly mentioned.

Function `member` has to be renamed and looks like this:

```
(define (my-member v lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #false)
        ((= v (car lst)) #true)
        (else (my-member v (cdr lst)))))
```

(Built-in function `member` actually returns list, but this can be enough.)

With `insert`, you have to check if your list already contains that element and in that case, return it as is.

```
(define (insert v lst)
  (if (my-member v lst)
      lst
      (cons v lst)))
```

Example:

```
> (insert 3 '(1 2 3))
'(1 2 3)
> (insert 4 '(1 2))
'(4 1 2)
```

You may also find [`check-duplicates`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._check-duplicates%29%29) and [`remove-duplicates`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) useful and there is already [Racket library](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html) for working with sets.

Comment: I tried (display (member 4 (list 1 2 4))) and it gives me (4) instead of #t...how can I fix that?

Comment: @TheCoder You are using built-in function `member`, which returns list or `#f`, and list is truthy value, so it works inside `if` as expected: `(if (member 2 '(1 2 3)) "yes" "no")` or `(if (member 5 '(1 2 3)) "yes" "no")`... if you want return only `#t` or `#f`, use my function `my-member`.

Comment: OH got it! Thanks